# exterior algebra as an ideal of tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have seen exterior algebra defined as a quotient  of tensor algebra by a two sided Ideal. But is it possible to define just the $p$th order exterior algebra from the tensor product of the same order as some kind of quotient?

Comment: "without using alternative forms as some kind of quotient" I am struggling to parse this

Comment: The $p$-th order exterior algebra is not a algebra, but mereley a linear space. And yeah, you can do it, just restrict the ideal to the $p$-th order tensors and form the quotient space.